# Spring Boot custom model on top of another

Tags: spring-boot, rest, kotlin

I'm new to Spring Boot and I don't know how to google this, but

I have this situation:

There is table `tokens`:

```
id INT
token VARCHAR
type VARCHAR
resource VARCHAR
attributes JSON
created_at DATETIME
```

And this tokens are multi-purpose: login codes, share codes etc

Login process:

1. E-mail provided by user
2. Server sent login code to e-mail
3. User provides code
4. Authorization

So in login context, I don't have Token with `resource` and `attributes`, but I have `LoginCode` model which properties `code` `userId` (stored as `resource`) and `created_at`

So i have model class and repository:

```kotlin
@Entity
class Token(
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Column(unique = true)
    var token: String = generateToken(6),

    var type: TokenType,

    var resource: String,

    @Type(type = "json")
    var attributes: Map<String, Any>? = null,

    var createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
)

interface TokenRepository : CrudRepository<Token, Long> {
    fun findByTokenAndType(token: String, type: TokenType)
}
```

But is there a better solution for custom repository than:

```kotlin
interface LoginCodeRepository : TokenRepository {
    fun findByCode(code: String): LoginCode {
        val token = this.findByTokenAndType(
            token = code,
            type = TokenType.LOGIN_ATTEMPT,
        )
        return LoginCode.fromToken(token)
    }

    fun create(adminId: Long): LoginCode {
        val token = this.save(Token(
            type = TokenType.LOGIN_ATTEMPT,
            resource = adminId.toString(),
        ))
        return LoginCode.fromToken(token)
    }
}
```

Without showing the whole TokenRepository api for public, and not having to call LoginCode.fromToken in each function?

Answer (score 0):

You have entity Token. And you don't need special repository for each purpose using of token. You can make data class (model) for Login. And then you can make in separate utils file extension functions for conversion between Token entityi to different models like Login. I'll show you some example:

```
@Entity
data class Token(
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null,

    @Column(unique = true)
    var token: String = generateToken(6),

    var type: TokenType,

    var resource: String,

    @Type(type = "json")
    var attributes: Map<String, Any>? = null,

    var createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
)

data class LoginCode(
    val code: String,
    val userId: String,
    val createdAt: LocalDataTime
)

fun Token.toLoginCode() = LoginCode(
    code = this.token,
    userId = this.resource,
    createdAt = this.createdAt
)
```

Then in your service layer, if you will need LoginCode, you can do something like this:

```
tokenRepository.findByTokenAndType(code, TokenType.LOGIN_ATTEMPT).toLoginCode()

tokenRepository.save(Token(type = TokenType.LOGIN_ATTEMPT, resource = adminId.toString())).toLoginCode()
```